# How many bits/questions does it take to identify the most frequent number in an array?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity

Note that "most frequent" here means "any of the most frequent, don't care which".
Example $n=3$. Consider the Bell partitions
aaa
aab
aba
baa
abc
which subsume all possibilities of a 3 element array A (different letters are different values). You just need one question: Are the last two elements equal? If yes, return the last of the array. If no, return the first.
If logical combinations (like "is there at least one = between the last four elements?") are allowed, I'd expect, of course, $<log_2(B_n)$ questions, where $B_n$ is the corresponding Bell number. The tricky part is that you may return the array number most convenient for your algorithm, and as the example shows, less than the above upper bound will suffice. (Two for $n=4$, at most five for $n=5$. Also note that the actual number of IF statements possibly will be higher as two independent questions with four possible answers need three IF, and "five" refers to my actual IF...ELSE IF... construct, but for explicite algorithm details, I pester StackOverflow :-) I'd be happy with a sharper bound at the moment.)

Comment: What kind of queries do you allow? (With no restrictions, one can trivially find the answer using a single $n$-valued query, or $\log_2 n$ binary queries.)

Comment: Maybe this answers your question? [Boyer-Moore 
 majority vote algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm)

Comment: Seems like a good question for CodeGolf.SE :-)

Comment: @Emil: Extremely good point, which I did not phrase very well. I *do* allow unrestricted queries, and they *do* solve trivially, but this is cheating. :-) For example, the n=4 case I solve by IF 2nd=oneoflasttwo 2 ELSE 3rd=4th 3 ELSE 1 ENDIF. This is very OK as an algorithm but the factual costs are 3 when stated in = operations, and THAT I want to know.

Comment: @Jay: Sorry, not exactly! It finds a "strong" majority but I'd like to know a "weak" majority. Note 3 in the wiki seems very relevant. THX.

Comment: @Nate: Actually, if the numbers are not too large, this algorithm http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-repeating-number-in-ok-time/ is perfect. Unfortunately, my numbers may be huge. I thus made a code that "relabels" them first, and indeed it works in O(m) (m arraylength) time. Even more unfortunately, the prefactor is so huge that this becomes relevant only when m is 100 or so (and I rarely would need more than 10) and my cheap O(m^2) code (write all comparisons into a m*m matrix, sum over col, then max over row) is faster.

Comment: @Nate: Been there, done that: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42529/mode-most-common-element-of-a-list/108850#108850 But this optimizes the program length (or rather language? :-), rather than the runtime...

Comment: I still don’t quite understand what you are saying. If you formally allow arbitrary queries, but regardless of that count the number of equality queries that are needed to implement them, how is that any different from just only allowing equality queries? Anyway, it is easy to show that in that case, any algorithm needs at least $\binom{n-1}2$ equality queries in the worst case, hence you basically cannot beat the trivial $\binom n2$ algorithm that compares everybody to everybody.

Comment: @Hauke: In the question you write that "Two for n=4", but in your first comment you write that the "factual costs are 3" [in the n=4 case] - so it would be nice to state your problem more explicitly.

Comment: @domotorp - The first if checks 2=3 and 2=4. The second 3=4. Two IF but three comparisons.

Comment: @Emil: OK, if I will still need O(m^2) then you answered my questions in the negative - no effective speedup is possible. (Of course, the *factual* speedup due to the prefactors is still rather impressive - the n=3 IF version runs 5x faster than the matrix-sum-max version.)

Comment: @Emil: But note that with the following comparisons for n=6 which are not exactly elegant: IF (4=5&4=6) ELSEIF (3=4&3=5)V(3=4&3=6)V(3=5&3=6) ELSEIF (1=2) ELSEIF (2=3&2=4)V(2=3&2=5)V(2=3&2=6) ELSEIF (2=4&2=5)V(2=4&2=6)V(2=5&2=6) ELSEIF (1=3V1=4V1=5V1=6) ELSEIF (2=3V2=4V2=5V2=6) ELSEIF (3=4V3=5V3=6) ELSEIF 4=5 ELSE ENDIF (with the obvious assignments) I still get a giant speedup vs. the "elegant" matrix code, even though I stored all comparison first. It would be interesting if a straightforward nested IF over all cases would be faster. Here I don't need any nesting.